# Trace Linux Kernel to find how many bytes read from disk in IO operation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, io, events

I have a Python script that reads Linux kernel system calls, using [LTTng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTTng). So with this script I could read all kernel events.

I have some IO operations (open and read file) and with this script I am going to analyze kernel events.

I need to know how many bytes have been read from cache and how many have been read from disk.

Which kernel events show me the number of bytes read from cache and disk?

Comment: From memory I don't think this count exists. Everything in some sense comes from the cache. It is just that when you read the cache and something is not there then you get a pagein event. I don't think I can help you more, but you could clarify your question. Are you trying to look at the overall effectiveness of the buffer cache or looking at one or more programs and how they use the cache? Perhaps `perf record -e page-faults -ag` is what you are looking for, rather than LTTng. Maybe even easier is `man time` and `%R` and `%F`. Hopefully someone else can help more.